# Joining one table two times

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My db schema:

```
tournaments(id, ...)
teams(tournament_id, id, ...)
matches(tournament_id, id, team_id_home, team_id_away, ...)
```

Models:

```
class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :matches, dependent: :destroy
    ...
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    ...
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    has_many :teams
    ...
end
```

I would like to have the following data in my view:

```
match_id  team_id_home  team_id_away  team_id_home_name  team_id_away_name
```

So, I'm asking for help with the following query (I'm trying to get team's names, but having problem with joining):

```
@matches = @tournament.matches.where(:tournament => @tournament).joins(:teams).paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is belongs_to, not has_one in Match model.

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    belongs_to :home_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_id_home"
    belongs_to :away_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_id_away"
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    has_many :matches
end
```

Now I can use tournament.home_team.name in my view

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to rails, but you should be able to setup your associations like this: (going from memory)

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :tournament
    has_one :home_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_id_home"
    has_one :away_team, :class_name => "Team", :foreign_key => "team_id_away"
end

#####

m = Match.first
m.away_team.team_name
m.home_tam.team_name
```

Or in your case:

```
@matches = @tournament.matches.paginate(page: params[:page])
```

I don't think you need the where function: the has_many association tells rails to only pull matching matches.

Comment: error: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: teams.team_id_home: SELECT  "teams".* FROM "teams"  WHERE "teams"."team_id_home" = ?  ORDER BY "teams"."id" ASC LIMIT 1